# Git monorepo layout with shared library

Tags: git, monorepo

We have two projects `A` and `B` with shared library `L`. To avoid duplication of `L`' s history, we are considering to set up a Git monorepo which will contain `A`, `B` and `L` on the top-level:

```
/
+-- L
|   +-- src
|
+-- A
|   +-- .idea (project metadata)
|   +-- src
|
+-- B
    +-- .idea (project metadata)
    +-- src
```

A local checkout of project `A` or `B` should contain `L` as sub-directory, like:

```
A
+-- .idea (project metadata)
+-- src
+-- L
    +-- src
```

Is this possible with Git and sparse checkouts or any other Git functionality? If not, is there an alternative repository layout which does not duplicate `L` and still gives above working tree structure?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible with Git and sparse checkouts ...

Yes: the relatively new *cone mode* sparse checkout is designed for this structure. See [How to use git sparse-checkout in 2.27+](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62423920/1256452) which describes how what worked in Git 2.25 broke in Git 2.27, and what you should do instead.

Note that you'll probably want Git 2.27 or 2.28.

Comment: Unfortunately what you are pointing to is not exactly what I'm looking for: we do not only need a sparse checkout of the existing repository structure, but also a slight rearrangement. In my example above, `L` which is actually a top-level repository directory should be moved below `A` in the local working tree.

Comment: @mstrap: ah, I see. If you have symbolic links, making a symlink from A would be a workaround, but aside from that, no: there's no easy way to have Git arrange the work-tree differently from the names of the files as stored in the repository. You could perhaps do something sneaky with `git checkout-index --prefix`, but that will get messy.