# How to use git sparse-checkout in 2.25 and not checkout everything

Tags: git, git-sparse-checkout

So after trying multiple [tutorials](https://github.blog/2020-01-17-bring-your-monorepo-down-to-size-with-sparse-checkout/), questions/[answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114887/is-it-possible-to-do-a-sparse-checkout-without-checking-out-the-whole-repository) I am still not able to get `git sparse-checkout` working on Windows 10 with `git 2.25`

**Background**

Our repo moved from `perforce` to `git` recently and now I am trying to get `git` working on Windows with my repo, but am failing miserably.

The repo itself is huge 20GB and there are files in there with names `aux.c,aux.h,nul` which are invalid in Windows. With Perforce it was simple to map only the required directory on Windows and work with it. I certainly don't need those files on Windows

**What I have been trying**

```
git clone --no-checkout --depth=1 <repo-url> test-dir
cd test-dir
git sparse-checkout init --cone
```

But the `sparse-checkout` tries to get a file named `nul` from a directory which fails

So I replaced `sparse-checkout init` with

```
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo 'automation/python/my-automation' >> .\git\info\sparse-checkout
git read-tree -mu HEAD
```

It again runs into that `invalid path` error due to `nul` file 'automation/ruby/.../nul'

I thought maybe I am running into issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62423920/how-to-use-git-sparse-checkout-in-2-27) so I downgraded `git` version from 2.27 to 2.25, without luck :(

How do I skip these unnecessary files from checkout and work with only one directory ? I can't ask the other teams to delete their files :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant `.git\info\sparse-checkout`, fixed now

Comment: Any help/inputs for this one ??

Comment: backslashes aren't path separators in the unix envirornment. Use forward slashes. Backslashes are syntax escapes.

Comment: @jthill I have tried both, could not get it working. The solution provided here, https://github.com/uvdl/linux-fslc/issues/1 doesn't work for me

Comment: This one seems to be similar. `core.protectNTFS false` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63727594/github-git-checkout-returns-error-invalid-path-on-windows

Answer (score -1):

The file `nul` is a prohibited filename on Windows. There is a set of similar filenames that are prohibited.

see https://brendanforster.com/notes/fixing-invalid-git-paths-on-windows/ for possible work arounds.

Comment: This links is asking to modify the files. But as I said in my post, those files are not owned by me so I can't touch them at all